# How to Use @Html.EditorFor() without the view model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, editorformodel

I want to do something like this so I can create a modal dialog that I'll invoke late with jQuery

```
<div class="modal" id="modalName" style="display: none;">
<div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
    <h3>Edit Contacts</h3>
</div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "form-horizontal" } }))
{
    <div class="modal-body">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => new ViewModel(), "ViewModelTemplateName")
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            Submit</button>

    </div>
}
</div>
```

On this line

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => new ViewModel(), "ViewModelTemplateName")
```

I get the error

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access,
>   single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer
>   expressions.

I don't understand why it would care where or what the instance is (as long as its the right type)

@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/ViewModel.cshtml", new ViewModel()) does the trick, but I have to declare the full path the the template...this sucks a bit.

so is there a better way to do it?

Comment: sorry that was a typo (to protect the innocent) I'll edit and fix.

Comment: Yes but consuming the model isn't always what you want to do. Data Annotations are good they give us nice validations and pretty names. When I want to do something richer with my pages in jQuery it nice just to render the viewmodel into a template and them let things like knockoutjs and twitter-bootstrap do its magic.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Technically it's not the *instance* that's the problem.  It's an *expression*, not a function, that you're passing there and the expression parser used by `EditorFor`, to get the meta data it uses to identify the properties etc, doesn't support `new` expressions.

You can simply declare a new instance of the model outside of the EditorFor statement and do this:

```
@{ var emptyViewModel = new ViewModel(); }
@Html.EditorFor(model => emptyViewModel, "ViewModelTemplateName")
```

That should work.

That said - *not* using part of the `model` in the expression is a little weird.  You should perhaps consider extracting the dialog out to it's own partial view that has `ViewModel` as it's model type, and then you can use `EditorForModel` in that, and call it from this parent view using a `new ViewModel()` as the model you pass to it.

Comment: Yep that worked, thanks...and you're right about making partial views. I'm looking into making that happen now.